# SQL: Getting two max values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQLquery

```
SELECT r.ShopId, r.PosId , max_Temp, r.DateTime
FROM dbo.Reports r
inner join 
(Select 
rp.ShopId,
rp.PosId ,
max(T.ref.value ('TEMPERATURE[1]', 'varchar(50)')) as  max_Temp
FROM db.[dbo].[Reports] rp CROSS APPLY Snippet.nodes ('/HARDWARE_INFO/CPU_INFO/CORE') as T(ref) 
group by rp.ShopId, rp.PosId ) a
on a.ShopId = r.ShopId and a.PosId = r.PosId 
inner join 
(Select 
rp.ShopId,
rp.PosId ,
MAX(rp.DateTime) as max_date
FROM db.[dbo].[Reports] rp 
group by rp.ShopId, rp.PosId ) b
on a.ShopId = r.ShopId and a.PosId = r.PosId and b.max_date = r.DateTime 

GROUP BY r.ShopId, r.PosId, r.DateTime, a.max_Temp
```

I am trying to return the PosId,ShopId, Max_Temp and the max_date.
The max_date is the only one not working right now. 
It always returns the max value of the entire table instead of the maximum date of the value with the maximum temperature.

So Basically i want to find out the max_temp for each ShopId/PosId (this will give multiple values because the max_temp could be measured on different dates) with the highest date of that list.

Comment: Oh boy, are you joining to an XML-field and extracting certain data from the xml? Thats going to be great for performance :)

Comment: I know, but i have no other choice in this one.. Can't change the table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
Select * From Report
Where row_number() over (partition by PosId,ShopId Order By temp desc) = 1
```

Or

```
Select r.* From Report as r
Inner join (select PosId,ShopId, max_temp = max(temp) From report group by PosId, ShopId)  as m
on m.PosId = r.PosId and m.ShopId = r.ShopId and r.temp = m.Max_temp
```

It may not work very well with xml. (meaning slow and inneficient)

```
select ShopId, PosId, Temp, Datetime From (
    Select 
    rp.ShopId,
    rp.PosId ,
    T.ref.value ('TEMPERATURE[1]', 'varchar(50)') as  Temp,
    row_number() over (partition by rp.ShopId, rp.PosId Order By T.ref.value ('TEMPERATURE[1]', 'varchar(50)') desc) as n
    FROM db.[dbo].[Reports] rp CROSS APPLY Snippet.nodes ('/HARDWARE_INFO/CPU_INFO/CORE') as T(ref) 
) as mx
where mx.n = 1
```

Comment: I am not sure on how i would add those lines in my query

Comment: the Last code gives the error 'incorrect syntax near 'over' *EDIT* nvm there was a ')' to much.

Comment: Did you try to fix it? You have mismatched number ( ). I can't edit right now. Remove one before as temp

Comment: I can't edit your post either. but it is working if the ')' is removed